# mocha global `before` that executes only 1 time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, functional-testing

I'm using mocha for node.js functional testing.

There are several files in my test.

How can I run a piece of code for only one time before all tests start?

For example, I may have to set up a docker container before all tests start.
Is it possible to do this with mocha?

The [`before`](https://mochajs.org/) hook runs 1 time for every test file. This doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: The easiest way I have found so far is to create a file with a name starting with underscore, e.g. `_before.test.js` which will run before the other tests since mocha loads them alphabetically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have 'root' level hooks, if you put them outside of any describe blocks. So you can put your relevant code in any files inside of the test folder.

```
before(function() {
  console.log('before any tests started');
});
```

See the docs: http://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks

Answer (score 2):

Mocha 8 introduces the concept of [root hook plugins](https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins). In your case, the relevant ones are `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, which will run once before/after all tests, so long you tests run in serial.

You can write:

```js
exports.mochaHooks = {
  beforeAll(done) {
    // do something before all tests run
    done();
  },
};
```

And you'll have to add this file using the `--require` flag.

See [docs](https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very clean solution for this. Use [--file](https://mochajs.org/#--file-file) as parameter in your mocha command. It works like a **global hook** for your tests.

```
xargs mocha -R spec --file <path-to-setup-file>
```

A setup file can look like this:

```
'use strict';
const mongoHelper = require('./mongoHelper.js');

console.log("[INFO]: Starting tests ...");
// connect to database

mongoHelper.connect()
.then(function(connection){
  console.log("[INFO]: Connected to database ...");
  console.log(connection);
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.error("[WARN]: Connection to database failed ...");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Unfortunately I have not found a way to use async/await in this setup files. So I think you may have to be conent with using "old" promise and callback code.